# How to remove a dead third-party app from your SO applications?

Tags: support

There's a 3rd-party application called `GuruDigger RobotPerputual` linked to my SO account. But I cannot remove it.

- The *Remove* button gives no response and won't remove the link
- The website of the application, https://gurudigger.com/, is gone

Maybe I need some SO support to help me remove it?

Comment: Tangentially... what is (or was) a "guru digger"?

Comment: An exhumation service for experts?